# fade in then fadout in jquery for some seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if I can make my div do something just to look more attractive . However , I want my div to fade in then go back normally automatically . I tried fade in for seconds with a function ,, but I need it to be back quickly . How can this be done ? Any help ? Thankyou

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.setTimeout("fadeMyDiv();", 3000); //call fade in 3 seconds
 }
)

function fadeMyDiv() {
   $("#test").fadeOut('slow')

}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: sorry , Please check it back

Comment: Do you want the div to **fade in** first then **wait some** seconds then **fade out**?

Comment: not too much seconds ,,Just on eye look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` accept another parameter which is a callback function that get called when the fade in/out is done. You can use it like:

```
var $div = $("#test");
$div.fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $div.fadeOut("slow");
});
```

And you can use [**`delay`**](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) to make a delay between the fade in and out:

```
$("#test").fadeIn("slow")     // fade in
          .delay(1000)        // wait 1000 ms (1 second)
          .fadeOut("slow");   // fade out
```

**Loop forever:**

```
var $div = $("#test");
setInterval(function() {
    $div.fadeIn("slow", function() { $div.fadeOut("slow"); });
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thankk youu ,, how can I permit this to be done every two seconds ?

Comment: hahahahah no  but I need the idea only ;p  certainly I  wont do that

Comment: You can use `setInterval` for that. I'll add an example.

Comment: @gfdfgffgfdfg just make sure the 2 seconds are enough for the div to fade in/out. As you had specified that the fade in/out is `"slow"`.

Comment: I will change it